# How insert Multiple checkbox value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, codeigniter-query-builder

I need to insert multiple values in the checkbox in Codeigniter.  how I can write this in the controller.
I tried so many but the values not inserting .

**View.Php**

```
<div class="custom-file">
 <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Medium"> M 
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Large">L
 <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="XL"> XL
</div>
```

Model

```
public function product_insert($data)
{
    // grab user input
    $this->db->insert('product', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function newProduct()
{
    $data   = array();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('admin/product_model');
    $this->load->model('admin/category_model');

    $data['category']   = $this->category_model->active_category_listing();
   // $data['brand']        = $this->product_model->brand_listing();
   
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');

    // Validating  Field
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_title', 'Title', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('admin/add_product', $data);
    } 
         //insert size checkboxes into database.
         $sizeArray = $this->input->post('size');  // Array
       
         $sizeString = implode(",", $sizeArray);    // String
    else {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/product_images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = 10024;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        // upload file to directory
        $uploadedFile ='';
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('product_img')) {
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadedFile = $uploadData['file_name'];
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $uploadData['full_path'];
            $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/product_images/thumb';
            $config['create_thumb'] = false;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width']         = 311;
            $config['height']       = 415;
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            
            $data['success_msg'] = 'File has been uploaded successfully.';
        } else {
            $data['error_msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        // Setting values for tabel columns
        $data = array(
            'product_title' => $this->input->post('product_title'),
            'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description'),
            'product_price' => $this->input->post('product_price'),
            'product_discount' => $this->input->post('product_discount'),
            'product_quantity' => $this->input->post('product_quantity'),
            'sub_category_id' => $this->input->post('sub_category_id'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'product_status' => $this->input->post('product_status'),
            'product_img' => $uploadedFile,
            'product_key'   => random_string('alnum',8),
            'product_cuttingprice'   => $this->input->post('product_cuttingprice'),
            'size'=>$sizeString);

        );
        // Transfering data to Model
        $prdID  = $this->product_model->product_insert($data);
        $upImg      = $this->uploadAddtnlImages($prdID);    
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Product Added Successfully');
        redirect('admin/product/listProduct/', 'refresh');

    }

}
```

Comment: where you taking size input in controller??

Comment: am not taking how to take that  KUMAR

Comment: where you getting problem??

Comment: i dnt know how i can put this KUMAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**View:-**

You must do all name checkbox as an `array` like this.

```
<div class="custom-file">
 <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Medium"> M 
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="Large">L
 <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="XL"> XL
</div>
```

**Controller:-**

```
       public function newProduct()
{
    $data   = array();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('string');
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('admin/product_model');
    $this->load->model('admin/category_model');

    $data['category']   = $this->category_model->active_category_listing();
   // $data['brand']    = $this->product_model->brand_listing();
   
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>');

    // Validating  Field
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_title', 'Title', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->load->view('admin/add_product', $data);
    } 
          else {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/product_images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = 10024;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        // upload file to directory
        $uploadedFile ='';
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('product_img')) {
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            $uploadedFile = $uploadData['file_name'];
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $uploadData['full_path'];
            $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/product_images/thumb';
            $config['create_thumb'] = false;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width']         = 311;
            $config['height']       = 415;
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            
            $data['success_msg'] = 'File has been uploaded successfully.';
        } else {
            $data['error_msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
        
         //insert size checkboxes into database.
         $sizeArray = $this->input->post('size');  // Array
       
         $sizeString = implode(",", $sizeArray);    // String
  
        // Setting values for tabel columns
        $data = array(
            'product_title' => $this->input->post('product_title'),
            'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description'),
            'product_price' => $this->input->post('product_price'),
            'product_discount' => $this->input->post('product_discount'),
            'product_quantity' => $this->input->post('product_quantity'),
            'sub_category_id' => $this->input->post('sub_category_id'),
            'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
            'product_status' => $this->input->post('product_status'),
            'product_img' => $uploadedFile,
            'product_key'   => random_string('alnum',8),
            'product_cuttingprice'   => $this->input->post('product_cuttingprice'),
            'size'=>$sizeString);

        );
        // Transfering data to Model
        $prdID  = $this->product_model->product_insert($data);
        $upImg      = $this->uploadAddtnlImages($prdID);    
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Product Added Successfully');
        redirect('admin/product/listProduct/', 'refresh');

    }

}
```

**Model Code:-**

```
public function product_insert($data)
{
    // grab user input
    $this->db->insert('product', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

**Note:-** For More info regarding `implode()`.

The `implode()` function returns a string from the elements of an array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: can you implement that in my code i applied this one my code its showing error kumar

Comment: @Alex now try with my updated answer please & let me know what happens??

Comment: please check my question code once more now I edited  and updated the code now its showing Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)     KUMAR